# Attempt to call free on non-heap object warning on heap object

Tags: c, clion

I am coding a simple parser in C as an assignment, and I'm trying to reuse as much code as I can from the previous one. I had the following snippets:

Tokens:

```
typedef struct token {
    const char *lexeme;   //the actual string value of the token
    Category category;  //the category of the token
} Token;

Token create_token(const char *lexeme, Category cat) {
    Token token = {.lexeme = lexeme, .category = cat};
    return token;
}
```

Automatas:

```
typedef struct automata {
    //does not directly store token but is easy to retrieve
    Category token_type;    //which type of token is the automata supposed to scan
    char *scanned;  //char buffer to store read characters from a string. Not realloced because it's been given reasonable capacity

    int lexeme_capacity;    //capacity of scanned buffer. Dynamic change is not implemented, all tokens should be at most this length
    ...
} Automata;

Automata create_automata(int num_states, char *accepted_chars,
                         int num_accepted_states, const int *accepted_states,
                         Category token_type) {
    ...
    //create and return an automata
    Automata automata = {
            .token_type = token_type,
            //TODO malloc returns an allocated pointer so it is not null but it must take into account possible overflows
            .scanned = malloc(DEFAULT_LEXEME_LENGTH * sizeof(char)),
            .lexeme_capacity = DEFAULT_LEXEME_LENGTH,
            ...
    };

    return automata;
}


Token get_token(Automata *automata) {
    // if automata is not in accepting state, it did not recognize the lexeme
    Category category = accept(automata) ? automata->token_type : CAT_NONRECOGNIZED;

    // easy to understand if written like this
    Token value = {
            .lexeme = automata->scanned,
            .category = category,
    };

    return value;
}
```

From what I understand, any token I create using the `get_token` function is going to contain a `char *`to heap memory. This worked fine for my previous assignment.

As part of the current assignment, I want to be able to read tokens from a file. Since I can't just have a token contain a pointer to data on a file, I've created the following functions to directly create a token from stack memory:

```
Token allocate_token(const char *lexeme, size_t lexeme_len, Category cat) {
    //allocate and copy into heap memory the contents of the lexeme string
    char *heap_allocated = calloc(lexeme_len + 1, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(heap_allocated, lexeme, lexeme_len * sizeof(char));

    //create and return a token
    return create_token(heap_allocated, cat);
}

void free_token(Token *token) {
    free(&token->lexeme);
}
```

However, CLion warns that the `free_token` function is "attempting to call free on non-heap object 'lexeme'". I can't see how `lexeme` would not be a heap allocated pointer.
I want to know if I'm missing or not understanding something or if I can just ignore this warning.

Comment: `free(&token->lexeme)` Think hard about the address you're passing to `free` there. Hint: `&token->lexeme` is not synonymous with `token->lexeme`. the former is the address **of** a member variable; the latter is the address **held** by a member variable. Related, this is a recipe for disaster regardless, since `lexeme` is `const char *` in the first place. it has no conversion to `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling `free(token->lexeme)` the compiler should complain that you are calling `free` with a `const` qualified pointer, which is incorrect as `free` expects a `char *` argument.

Ensuring you call `free` with a pointer to allocated memory is your responsibility, but storing that to a `const char *` makes it harder to track the object lifetime and to differentiate between pointers to heap objects and pointers to constant data such as string literals.

If the string pointed to by `lexeme` is meant to be freed by `free`, it should have type `char *` and you must ensure that `lexeme` is always either set to `NULL` or set to a pointer to allocated memory that is owned by the `token` structure, ie: that will only get freed by `free_token()`.  This may imply duplicating strings with `strdup() to ensure the` token`owns its`lexeme`.

**EDIT:**

From your updated question, `free_token` calls `free(&token->lexeme);`. This is wrong. You pass the address of the structure item instead of its value. You might have added this extra `&` as a fix for another compiler error, for which the above explanation should give you some hints.

Comment: Thank you, where can I find the differences between `const char*` and `char*`? I thought const was only useful to signal to the compiler that it could do some optimizations.

Comment: @Pollastre no it is information that the object is immutable. https://godbolt.org/z/qE6hfGEra

Comment: But it is not the main issue in OPs code. The main issue is that he wants to free the member of the struct not the the value held by this member (ie reference to the allocated memory)

Comment: @0___________: there is so little code in the question, it is difficult to analyze how the memory is managed if at all.

Comment: `free(&token->lexeme);` - not ralated to `const`, but real source of his problems

Comment: @0___________: yes indeed, but passing the value instead of the address of `token->lexeme` would let him hit the `const` issue.

Comment: @chqrlie I had no memory management because any token I would make would point to a string in heap memory held by an automata struct. I had a function to free the pointers in the automata, but that was not relevant to the issue I had. My issue was how to free this `char*`in the token struct. Your answer already solves that, thanks!